# Retrieving applicationContext object using ApplicationContextAware interface implementation

Tags: java, spring

Said problem will get resolved if the class implementing `ApplicationContextAware` is marked with `@Component` annotation and class/residing package is mentioned as part of `@ComponentScan` annotation. If the class is not part of the scanned packages, then this won't work.

Do not want to initialise new Context as I need to extend the properties of the main application, is there any alternative for this.
In short, I have an utility which is built with spring framework, callee application will also be implemented using Spring, but the utility does not have control over the packages that needs to be mentioned under `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: If you need to extend properties adding a class that might or might not be started isn't the proper approach. Please show the class and explain what you are trying to do, I suspect there are better ways to do this.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, Thanks for the answer. Basically, I am trying to write a utility which will invoke the rest API. Now this utility will be referred as a dependency on the other application built with spring-boot. Here the rest API URLs will be written to my applications config place holder from the application-dev.yaml. In the main application, these config place holders will be mentioned if there is any change it will get updated too. So I need to use the same context which is created by Spring Boot. Hope this explains..

Comment: No it doesn't and I don't see why you would need go through hoops for that. If the utility is using spring then provide instructions how to use it, you have some hooks (for Spring Boot at least) to automatically load classes.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, if we need to use any spring utility containing annotations, needs to be mentioned as part of @ComponentScan, at least the @Configuration bean of utility jar, so that it will scan further if there is anymore @ComponentScan annotations.

Note here that, it is not ideal to create separate ApplicationContext object as the dependent library is also part of the Spring application and ApplicationContext is initialised already during the startup of the application.

Above means, for the question raised here does not have direct solution.